# Check some field before opening confirmation box in ODOO

Tags: odoo, odoo-11, confirmation

I want to check that if some fields in the form view has been checked or not. If they have been checked then show a confirmation message and if not then a error message saying that those fields must be checked. For this functionality I have created a button which calls a specific function in the model. The button has also attribute confirm which enables the confirmation pop up box. But all the time it first opens the confirmation message and then the checking for the fields. I want to have the other way around how to achieve this. Please help.

Comment: You have just to ``raise`` an  `odoo.exceptions.UserError` inside the function.

Comment: @Kenly it still pops up the confirmation box first, i need to get the confirmation box later

Comment: The ``confirm`` attribute is used to ask users if they want to run the button function, which is no necessary in this case. You need to raise a warning when the function return False and do nothing when it returns True. You can also return an action which will open a form view to show a custom dialog.